# Terminology when Initializing C Structures

Tags: c, initialization, terminology

This will be an easy question but googling around does not seem to provide me with an answer. The way I understand it in C we have two ways to initialize a foo object, when foo is a structure. Look at the code below for an example

```
typedef struct foo
{
   int var1;
   int var2;
   char* var3;
}foo;

//initializes and allocates a foo
foo* foo_init1(int v1,int v2,const char* v3)
{
   if(..some checks..)
      return 0;
   foo* ret = malloc(sizeof(foo));

   ret->var1 = v1;
   ret->var2 = v2;
   ret-var3 = malloc(strlen(v3)+1);
   strcpy(ret->var3,v3);

   return ret;
}

// initializes foo by ... what? How do we call this method of initialization?
char foo_init2(foo* ret,int v1,int v2, const char* v3)
{
   //do some checks and return false
    if(...some checks..)
         return false//;assume you defined true and false in a header file as 1 and 0 respectively
   ret->var1 = v1;
   ret->var1 = v1;
   ret->var2 = v2;
   ret-var3 = malloc(strlen(v3)+1);
   strcpy(ret->var3,v3);

   return true;
}
```

So my question is this. How do we refer in C to these different initializing methods? The first returns an initialized pointer to foo so it's easy to use if you want a foo object on the heap like that:

```
foo* f1 = foo_init1(10,20,"hello");
```

But the second requires a foo .. what? Look at the code below.

```
foo f1;
foo_init2(&f1,10,20,"hello");
```

So the second method makes it easy to initialize an object on the stack but how do you call it? This is basically my question, how to refer to the second method of initialization.

The first one allocates and initializes a pointer to foo.
The second one initializes a foo by ... what? Reference?

As a bonus question, how do you guys work when coding in C? Do you determine the usage of the object you are making and by that determine if you should have an initializing function of type1 , or 2 or even both of them?

Comment: I like to call them `_new` for the one that allocates and `_init` for the one that doesn't. Also, have `_new` call `_init` internally to make your code easier to maintain. (Sometimes I call it `_make` instead of `_new`.)

Comment: Hey Chris nice insight on the way you call them. Why don't you make this an answer so that I can vote it up and also potential SO users who have the same question can see it? 
Also ... is there no standard way for people to refer to them? I want someone looking at my code (since it's an API) to immediately understand the different usage just by the function name

Comment: @ChrisLutz: Just to be clear, you append `_new`, `_init` to the type name, right (`foo_new`, `foo_init`)?  Otherwise you'd be colliding with identifiers that are reserved to the implementation.  (I'm sure you know this; others might not.)

Comment: yeah ofc he does that >.< but I guess clarifications are very important in a Q&A site

Comment: @ChrisLutz "new" has no meaning in C, and therefore is a suboptimal choice for conveying intent. Allocation and initialization are what you're talking about, and foo_alloc() and foo_init() are both immediately understandable and completely unmistakable to speakers of C.

Comment: @tbert Thought of the same thing, new being a C++ keyword and all. Ofcourse on the other hand new is immediately recognizable to C++ speakers but this is C code. Hmm .. interesting discussion. I am inclined towards _init and _alloc right now. (Why don't you guys also input them as answers so that I can have the choice of accepting them?)

Comment: @KeithThompson - Yes, I was just typing from my phone and being lazy. @tbert - I know, but it's a consistent word to use and it's not terribly hard to understand. `make` is, IMHO, as good as `alloc` as far as semantic meaning. @Lefteris - I'm mainly not answering because phone typing is cumbersome.

Comment: @ChrisLutz No problem, don't wanna answer my own question so I will wait for one of the comments to become an answer. I have decided to go with Create and Init. I would have preferred alloc but for some reason it seems funny when written in my code so Create sounds really nice and also contrasts the way I free them with a _Destroy function very nicely.

At all: Thanks for the comments. Really helped me decide my naming convention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since none of the people in the comments took up on the offer to turn their comments into an answer I am forced to reply to my own question.

Well basically a possible answer would be that as AIs states there is no specific naming convention. Of course whatever naming method is used, it should be:

- **Consistent** across all of the project/s for clarity's sake
- **Recognizable** by other programmers as a function that does what it is actually doing.

To achieve that there were some great recommendations in the comments. For when a *foo* object is:

- Passed for initialization inside the function: *foo_init*
- Allocated inside the function and a pointer returned: *foo_alloc*, *foo_make* , *foo_new*

All of the above are clear I suppose but what is most accurately describes what is happening in the functions would be *foo_init* and *foo_alloc*.

Personally I really dislike the _alloc solution because I don't like how it looks in my code so I decided to add the verb _create instead of alloc after the function to denote what it's doing.

But well what the answer boils down to I guess is personal preference. All should be okay and acceptable as long as the functionality of the function is made clear by reading its name.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there are any well defined nomenclature for the two methods,
In the first method the function dynamically allocates a structure and assigns values to the members,
while in second the structure is allocated before the function and the function then just assigns values to the members.

> Do you determine the usage of the object you are making and by that determine if you should have an initializing function of type1 , or 2 or even both of them?

Selecting first or second method depends on a important difference:
The first method is preferred when you need to pass the returned structure across scopes, the memory on heap has to be explicitly freed untill which the data prevails while in Second method the data on stack gets removed once the scope of the passed object ends.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I know the difference between the two different methods so my question is if say you ... need to do both of the things you say in your last paragraph. Would you have both of the initialization functions and use each one when appropriate?

Also since I am not a native english speaker can you please just give me a term to name the second function with. This is the main reason I made the question, cause I wanted to name the functions in my code base